# SoundCloud Libraries Not Found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, libraries, soundcloud

I'm having some trouble with the SoundCloud API for iOS. I've followed the directions on their quickstart guide ([here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart)) and set my Header Search Path like [so](http://f.cl.ly/items/1v281z1c3G390s420K0G/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.48.10.png).

Xcode is finding SCUI.h and until recently wasn't getting any syntax errors. The app was running fine on the iOS Simulator and executing SoundCloud API requests (SCRequest methods). But I then went to try it on-device and encountered [these](http://f.cl.ly/items/3z3V021H2e1V0a1o173g/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.52.41.png) errors, then when I went back to trying to test on the Simulator I started getting [these](http://f.cl.ly/items/3c01132F3V0w3D3b103Q/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.55.52.png) errors.

After reading the error messages and checking my linked libraries ([here](http://f.cl.ly/items/2y3g073F1M05330G033x/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.58.23.png)) I'm certain it has something to do with the path that Xcode is searching for the headers. Or maybe those libraries just don't exist? I can't seem to see any them in Finder, even the .a files that are in black in my linked libraries section.

Also, I've tried cleaning the product (CMD+Shift+K). This allows the project to be run on the simulator but causes an "Assertion failure":

```
Assertion failure in -[NXOAuth2Client initWithClientID:clientSecret:authorizeURL:tokenURL:accessToken:tokenType:persistent:delegate:], /Users/chiliesontoast/Desktop/iOS/Projects/MobileX Labs/MXLTest App/MXLTestApp/OAuth2Client/Sources/OAuth2Client/NXOAuth2Client.m:82
```

And then when trying to build for a device it returns [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/1P3m311D3N0g0m073k3n/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2022.12.37.png) error.

Has anybody got any suggestions for a solution? It's been really bothering me all day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, finally fixed it! It was a combination of two things.

## First Issue

The first issue ([here](http://f.cl.ly/items/3z3V021H2e1V0a1o173g/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.52.41.png) and [here](http://f.cl.ly/items/3c01132F3V0w3D3b103Q/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-12%20at%2021.55.52.png)) was something to do with with the libraries and search paths. I did a load of different things, not sure what fixed it. I did this:

1. Changed the Header Search Paths around from "./**" to "$PROJECT_DIR" and finally to "../**", which is what it's at now.
2. Deleted all of the files downloaded for the SoundCloud API.
3. Deleted the entries for the downloaded submodules in .gitmodules and .git/config and then deleted all of the API's folders from .git/modules.
4. Then I removed the git cache by navigating to my project's root folder in Terminal and running:

   git rm --cache ./OAuth2Client

(And repeated for each of the added submodules).
I then reinstalled the SoundCloudAPI (using git) and possibly cleaned the project (CMD+Shift+K).

## Second Issue

The second issue was with a weird runtime error

```
Assertion failure in -[NXOAuth2Client initWithClientID:clientSecret:authorizeURL:tokenURL:accessToken:tokenType:persistent:delegate:], /Users/chiliesontoast/Desktop/iOS/Projects/MobileX Labs/MXLTest App/MXLTestApp/OAuth2Client/Sources/OAuth2Client/NXOAuth2Client.m:82
```

After some serious research into NXOAuth and looking at the stack trace I realised that I needed to include the following code in the function before trying to perform any SCRequest methods:

```
[SCSoundCloud setClientID:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                   secret:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"AppName://oauth"]];
```

So, that's how I went about solving it. I really hope this helps someone as I was stuck for a whole ~20 hours on this.

Comment: You are a life saviour! The documentation at the SoundCloudApi makes one think that setting Id and Secret is necessary only on setup, and not on every initialisation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Been fighting this one for a while... hit error after error (if anyone encounters a different one to this, message me - i guarantee I've hit it)

Anyway, what worked for me is that when you click on the project file, you have a choice of checking the build settings for the project or the target. It didn't work for me until I entered $PROJECT_DIR into the project build settings header search paths instead of the target build settings (or both)